# How to show when a changelist has files checked out?

Tags: version-control, perforce

By default, Perforce shows you whether a changelist has shelved files or files that need resolving or are stale. I want to know which changelists have files checked out. Is that possible?

Comment: You can use "p4 opened -a <file name> on each of the files in the change list, via a script, but it sounds from your question like you're looking for a way to do this directly in p4 (or maybe p4v).

Comment: @EricMiller yeah, looking for a visual way. I want to avoid expanding all changelists just too see which ones have files in them.

Comment: Are these your own changelists? Or the changelists of others? Pretty much '''every''' changelist has files checked out; completely empty changelists are (or should be) quite rare.

Comment: @BryanPendleton my changelists, and they're not rare, because I work on multiple stuff on parallel. So I just keep the ones that are on hold shelved.

Comment: If your workflow generates these empty pending changeslists frequently, then you might want to spend a few hours writing a simple script that runs 'changes -s pending -u your-name' and 'files @=change' to find all the empty ones for you; then it's easier to know which is which. Myself, I tend to delete my empty pending changeslists when I can.

Comment: @BryanPendleton they're not empty, they have shelved files in them. :)

Comment: Still found no way in Helix 2020 (September), I've sent a support ticket.

Comment: Looks like they already got a task for it, but they can't give public access to it, so you'll have to track latest updates regularly... Or just watch out when they add a "Show only pending changelists with checked out files" under the "Show only pending changelists with shelved files" checkbox in the Pending tab.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your pending "tab" in P4V
Empty the "workspace is" filter <- This will get you all changelists belonging to you, whether in your workspace or not
Filter by "user is" yourself <- to only get yours
Filter by "Files match any of the following file paths": `//*/...`
This will filter out any completely empty pending changelists (in general a lot of "default" ones, one by workspaces you have).

Now, you have two kind of changelists left in the tab view: The ones without a small file icon left to their triangle HAVE files checked out. The one with a small file icon left to their triangle have files on the shelf.

Unfortunately from P4V, I don't think it's possible to filter the ones with shelved files AND checked out files from the ones just with shelved files any better.